# CRUD tecnología dbExpress delphi

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, delphi, delphi-2010

CRUD tecnología dbExpress.

Estoy tratando de hacer un UPDATE a un registro en base de datos, pero me regresa error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Código:**

**.pas**

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfMain.ButtonGuardarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Guardar en BD
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  ClientDataSet1.Post;
  if ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0) <> 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error');
    ClientDataSet1.CancelUpdates;
  end;
  DataSource1.AutoEdit := False;
end;

procedure TfMain.ButtonEditarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  DataSource1.AutoEdit := True;
end;

procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SQLQuery1.Active then
    SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.Open;

  if ClientDataSet1.Active then
    ClientDataSet1.Close;
  ClientDataSet1.Open;

end;
```

**.frm**

```
object fMain: TfMain
  object Label1: TLabel
  end
  object cxGrid1: TcxGrid
    object cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView
      DataController.DataSource = DataSource1
      DataController.Summary.DefaultGroupSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.FooterSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.SummaryGroups = <>
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1TABLAA_ID: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'TABLAA_ID'
      end
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1TABLAA_NAME: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'TABLAA_NAME'
      end
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1TABLAC_ID: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'TABLAC_ID'
      end
    end
    object cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel
      GridView = cxGrid1DBTableView1
    end
  end
  object ButtonGuardar: TButton
    OnClick = ButtonGuardarClick
  end
  object ButtonEditar: TButton
    OnClick = ButtonEditarClick
  end
  object SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <>
    SQL.Strings = (
      'SELECT A.* '
      '  FROM PRUEBA_TABLAA A')
    SQLConnection = DataModule2.SQLConnection1
    object SQLQuery1TABLAA_ID: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TABLAA_ID'
      Required = True
    end
    object SQLQuery1TABLAA_NAME: TWideStringField
      FieldName = 'TABLAA_NAME'
    end
    object SQLQuery1TABLAC_ID: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TABLAC_ID'
    end
  end
  object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    object ClientDataSet1TABLAA_ID: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TABLAA_ID'
      Required = True
    end
    object ClientDataSet1TABLAA_NAME: TWideStringField
      FieldName = 'TABLAA_NAME'
    end
    object ClientDataSet1TABLAC_ID: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TABLAC_ID'
    end
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    AutoEdit = False
    DataSet = ClientDataSet1
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = SQLQuery1
  end
end
```

Pista: por defecto el TDataSetProvider está en UpdateMode = upWhereAll y al revisar la session en base de datos aparece:

```
UPDATE "PRUEBA_TABLAA"
   SET "TABLAA_NAME" = :1
 WHERE "TABLAA_ID" = :2 AND "TABLAA_NAME" = :3 AND "TABLAC_ID" = :4
```

Con el mensaje de error:

> Error: ORA-01722: número no válido

pero cuando lo configuro a

```
UpdateMode =
  upWhereKeyOnly
```

también me genera error y no puedo capturar la sentencia en base de datos.

> Error: Unable to find record. No key specified

Con `updateMode = upWhereChange`

Se ve el cambio reflejado en base de datos, pero al revisar la sentencia, esta no se realiza por llave primaria.

```
UPDATE "PRUEBA_TABLAA"
   SET "TABLAA_NAME" = :1
 WHERE "TABLAA_NAME" = :2
```

**¿Cómo configurar el TDataSetProvider para que actualice por llave primaria?**

**Edición 1:**

Con el evento OnReconcileError del ClientDataSet puedo capturar el mensaje de error:

```
procedure TfMain.ClientDataSet1ReconcileError(DataSet: TCustomClientDataSet;
  E: EReconcileError; UpdateKind: TUpdateKind; var Action: TReconcileAction);
begin
    ShowMessage('Error: '+E.Message);
end;
```

**Edición 2:**

Esquema de base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE PRUEBA_TABLAA 
(
TABLAA_ID FLOAT(126) NOT NULL,
TABLAA_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
TABLAC_ID NUMBER
);

COMMENT ON COLUMN PRUEBA_TABLAA.TABLAA_ID IS 'PK';

ALTER TABLE PRUEBA_TABLAA 
ADD CONSTRAINT TABLAA_C_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (TABLAA_ID);

INSERT INTO PRUEBA_TABLAA VALUES ('1','Nombre PRUEBA_TABLAA 1','1');
INSERT INTO PRUEBA_TABLAA VALUES ('2','Nombre PRUEBA_TABLAA 2','2');
INSERT INTO PRUEBA_TABLAA VALUES ('3','Nombre PRUEBA_TABLAA 3','3');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solución:

> Error: ORA-01722: número no válido

Se soluciono, colocando el mismo juego de caracteres númericos para los decimales en base de datos cómo en la aplicación con:

```
DecimalSeparator := '.';
```

y

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''
```

> ¿Cómo configurar el TDataSetProvider para que actualice por llave primaria?

Realmente no configure el TDataSetProvider sino el campo de la llave primaria en el TSQLQuery marcandolo cómo pfInKey

```
object SQLQuery1TABLAA_ID: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TABLAA_ID'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
      Required = True
      Precision = 32
    end
```

Ver documentación: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Influencing_How_Updates_Are_Applied

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, esto no es parte de la respuerta que buscas, pero como no puedo comentar te voy a indicar un par de cosas.

Si ya en el boton de Editar estas poniendo

```
ClientDataSet1.Edit;
```

Entonces porque razon en el boton de Guardar vuelves a poner

```
ClientDataSet1.Edit;
```

Por otro lado porque en ves de utilizar un TQuery no utilizas un TTable?

Los TQuery generalmente se utilizan para filtrar la información de forma más detallada y los TTable para el tema de la Edición.

Creo que si insertas un TTable, le asignas esa tabla que quieres editar, al DataSource le asignas como su dataSet al TTable y al cxGrid1TableView1 le asignas el DataSet antes mencionado, eso va a funcionar todo como por arte de magia, sin siquiera tener que poner una sola línea de código o simplemente escribir en el boton de guardar

```
Table1.Post;
```

Y en el boton de editar

```
Table1.Edit;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuestas, 1]) lo que pasa es que quiero editar multiples registros, si me cambio de registro luego no podré hacer ClientDataSet1.Post; debido a que el ClientDataSet1 ya no estará en Edit, me marca ese error. 2) utilizo un TQuery porque luego tendre que colocar mas filtros tipo where y otras tablas en el From. Aunque no descarto de plano la opción de Table, voy a revisarlo :)

Comment: Amigo mi correo es fidelhernandezsalazarARROBAgmail.com, si puedes escribeme un correo y nos ponemos de acuerdo para ayudarte. Tengo buena experticia en Delphi y te podría hechar una mano si gustas.

Comment: Ok @WoNDeR, Gracias :) voy a añadirte. Pero ese es todo el código, necestias algo más? mmm voy a agregar el esquema de la base de datos tambien.